# Did Donkey rescue the dragon?

Tags: shrek

When Shrek and Fiona first met Lord Farquaad, they get mad at each other, and Shrek goes back to his swamp. He also gets mad at Donkey, and he returns alone. Later, Donkey shows up, and he points out all Shrek's mistakes and helps him to get back to Fiona. For what they say, the castle is really far away and Donkey calls the dragon, who immediately shows up.

Did Donkey actually go all the way back to the dragon's castle, convince her that they are in love, unchain her and fly back to Shrek's in a few hours? (Since Fiona insisted in get married the same day.) I know it's a fairy tale, but it will be nice to have a canon answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Donkey didn't rescue Dragon.**

During the "Hallelujah" montage after Shrek returns to his swamp, Donkey is seen sitting mournfully at a river bank when he suddenly notices Dragon doing the same thing just a little way up the bank. His reaction makes it clear that he didn't realise she was there, but once he does, the two appear to silently bond with one another.

It's unclear how exactly Dragon managed to escape the castle, but it's most likely that she managed to unchain herself somehow. Donkey meeting her again afterwards was just a fortunate coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty clear from the [script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Shrek.html) that the dragon wasn't freed by Donkey. It describes her 'running into him'.

> Montage of different scenes. Shrek arriving back home. Fiona being fitted for the wedding dress. **Donkey at a stream running into the dragon.** Shrek cleaning up his house. Fiona eating dinner alone. Shrek eating dinner alone.

The film's [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/2291617) gives us a little more info about what she's been up to since Donkey left her at the tower.

> And Donkey? He was out in the world on his own—until, who should he
> bump into but his old friend the dragon. **He came upon her sitting by
> the river, looking sad and lonesome. She'd been looking for him.** She
> missed him. Feeling guilty, he sat down beside her, and they had
> a long, long talk.